# How to use VueJs component outside the app.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I am developing a single page application (SPA) using `Laravel` and `VueJs`. Where the `index.blade.php` page looks like:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" /> 
> </body>
> <body>
>   <div id="app">
>       <layout></layout>
>   </div>
> <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

The `layout.vue` component looks like:

> ```
> <template>
>     <div>
>         <input type="text" @keyup="search" />
>         <router-view></router-view>
>     </div>
> </template>
> <script>
> import router from 'router'
>
> export default {
>     data() {
>         return {
>             popover: false
>         }
>     },
>     methods: {
>         search: function (e) {/*Ajax code to search*/}
>     }
> }
> </script>
> ```

Everything is working fine except slower page loading at first. I see a white page until javascript works. So I've decided to put some html code in `index.blade.php`. I want to put the html from `layout.vue` page to `index.blade.php` so that I can see the html layout before javascript loads. How can I properly merge `layout.vue` with `index.blade.php` so that `@keyup` method works?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots